# Loop through variables in variable group in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

In an `azure-pipelines.yml` file, how do I enumerate all variables defined in a "Variable Group" created in the UI?

[image: Variable group]

I'd like to do this so I can write these variables to a `.env` file in the pipeline build stage.

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference at pipeline level between variables set in pipeline and those from variable group. But you can use Azure DevOps CLI to achieve your goal.

Please check [az pipelines variable-group variable list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/variable-group/variable?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_pipelines_variable_group_variable_list).

And this is the way how you can call CLI from pipeline - [Azure DevOps CLI in Azure Pipeline YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/azure-devops-cli-in-yaml?view=azure-devops)

Example for LINUX

```yaml
steps:
# Updating the python version available on the linux agent
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.x'
    architecture: 'x64'

# Updating pip to latest
- script: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  displayName: 'Upgrade pip'

# Updating to latest Azure CLI version.
- script: pip install --pre azure-cli --extra-index-url https://azurecliprod.blob.core.windows.net/edge
  displayName: 'upgrade azure cli'

- script: az --version
  displayName: 'Show Azure CLI version'

- script: az extension add -n azure-devops
  displayName: 'Install Azure DevOps Extension'

- script: echo ${AZURE_DEVOPS_CLI_PAT} | az devops login
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_CLI_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
  displayName: 'Login Azure DevOps Extension'

- script: az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName} project="Movie Search Web App" --use-git-aliases true
  displayName: 'Set default Azure DevOps organization and project'

- script: |
    az pipelines variable-group variable list --group-id 45
  displayName: 'Show variable group variables'
```

Comment: In that final script "Show variable group variables", is it possible to get the group by name instead of group-id?

Comment: @pjivers Looks like `az pipelines variable-group list` accepts a `--group-name` parameter that would limit the results that way instead of by the ID.  [MS Learn Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/variable-group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-variable-group-list)

Answer (score 2):

We could use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get%20variable%20groups%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and power shell script to loop the variable group

Create PAT token, save it to pipeline variable and set it to secret, then add task power shell and enter below script

Power shell script:

```
$connectionToken="$(pat)"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$URL = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?groupIds={Variable group ID}&api-version=6.0-preview.2"
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get 
 

$Variable = $Result.value.variables | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

Write-Host $Variable
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: if a variable is set to `secret` then the value will not be returned from the api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Variable Group Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevopsMindset.variable-group-formatter) extension. In outputFormat you can specify desired format like CLI or JSON

```
- task: VariableGroupFormatter@0
  name: variableGroup
  displayName: "Format variables"
  inputs:
    variableGroupID: '6'
    outputFormat: 'JSON'

- script: echo $(variableGroup.formattedVariables)
```

Result:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj2HE.png)